# CF2016 timeout on cfdirectory and directoryList to s3 AWS but works on CommandBox/Lucee

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, coldfusion, lucee

This command

```
<cfset thedirlist = directoryList(theimgthumbpath, false, "name", "", "asc", "dir")>
```

and this command

```
<cfdirectory directory="#theimgthumbpath#" action="list" recurse="false" name="thedirlist">
```

run into a timeout on our CF2016 server.
When I run the command from my local CommandBox/Lucee to the exact same bucket with the exact same key and secret it works ok.

`theimgthumbpath` :

> s3://#s3AccessKey#:#s3SecretKey#@#companybucket#/#projectname#/files/thumbnails/

The same on both environments.

`theimgthumbpath` contains 14 folders.

`directoryExists` give a `true`, also on CF2016

If I dive deeper, for example `theimgthumbpath/1200` (which contains 1800 files) again on CommandBox/Lucee it works fine and on CF2016 it runs into timeout.

I'd like to know what could be the cause of the timeout on CF2016 unlike on CommandBox/Lucee.
Since I have no idea where to start looking, I don't know what other details to provide.

Edit : On CF2016 I can perform actions on specific files in theimgthumbpath subfolders like copy up and down, setStoreACL() etc. But I cannot f.e. create a directory. I can on CommandBox/Lucee.

Comment: What are the exact errors you are getting. What do you get if you try/catch?  CF 2016/2018 implementation of S3 we always found terrible and had issues too. The new implementation of S3 in CF 2021 is light years ahead. The Lucee implementation may be similar which is why the result is better. I assume you are probably using a newer version of Lucee compared to the older CF2016.

Comment: @haxtbh I am not getting any errors, I have a try/catch. The call just doesn't return until timeout. In the network tab it keeps saying pending. Yes my Lucee version is newer

Comment: If you're in the market for a different library, here is a full fledged SDK for S3
https://www.forgebox.io/view/s3sdk

Comment: @BradWood I have been looking in the code our company has and found that in the past they used exactly that. I reinstalled some stuff and the only thing I have to do now is call a custom tag with some parameters and it gives me what I need. Although a very old version as far as I can see ('Copyright 2005-2007 ColdBox Framework') it does what I need, so good enough for now. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar slowness issues with S# access in Coldfusion 2016. So I created the following function to check for files with AWS SDK(You need to download SDK jar file and place it in CF_HOME\cfusion\lib for this to work). Using SDK for file operations are much more faster than Coldfusion 2016-18 implementations.

```
//Create SDK Client object
public any function getS3SDKClient(){
  local.objBasicAWSCredentials = createObject('java', 'com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials').init(application.s3key, application.s3secret);
  local.objAwsCreds = createObject('java', 'com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider').init(local.objBasicAWSCredentials);
  local.objRegions = createObject('java', 'com.amazonaws.regions.Regions');
  local.s3Client = createObject('java', 'com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder').standard()
                    .withRegion(local.objRegions.US_WEST_2)
                    .withCredentials(local.objAwsCreds)
                    .build();
  return local.s3Client;
}

//Check for file
public boolean function s3CheckFileExists(
  required string bucket,
  required string sourcePath
){
  local.s3Client = getS3SDKClient();
  return local.s3Client.doesObjectExist(arguments.bucket, arguments.sourcePath);
}

//Get list of files in path as an Aray
public array function s3GetPathFileList(
  required string bucket,
  required string sourcePath,
  string extensions = '' // list of extensions seperated by | pipe
){
  local.s3Client = getS3SDKClient();
  local.result = local.s3Client.listObjectsV2(arguments.bucket, arguments.sourcePath);
  local.fileList = [];
  for(local.item in local.result.getObjectSummaries()){
    if(len(trim(arguments.extensions)) == 0 || reFindNoCase("^.*\.(" & arguments.extensions & ")$", local.item.getKey())){
      local.fileList.append(local.item.getKey());
    }
  }
  return local.fileList;
}
```

I have heard S3 access in Coldfusion 2020 is way better than 2018. But if you cannot upgrade, then its easier to use this approach.

Comment: Thank you for offering your code. I did not know this SDK existed and will look into it.

Comment: I have been looking in all the code our company has and found that in the past they used  www.coldboxframework.com. All files are still there. Only thing I had to do was call a custom tag with some parameters. Although it looks like it is very old ('Copyright 2005-2007 ColdBox Framework') I can now list, create, delete folders etc. So I will stick to this for now.

Comment: @Veni Makes sense. Please mark this as the answer if you think it is correct.

Comment: Well tbh I am a bit in doubt to mark because 1st I cannot verify your function and can only assume it works :-) 2nd, As for the sdk part; until last month we worked with directly addressing a virtual /var/s3-amazon folder on our server to our bucket and that worked fine. Until suddenly copying files to this /var/s3-amazon, the files did not get the right permission anymore in the bucket. So we changed to directly addressing the aws bucket. And now, indeed I need an sdk, but before this permission issue, everything was just fine in CF2016 using the /var/s3-amazon folder.